# Change file permission in internal storage

Tags: android, file, permissions

I'd like to change the file permission.
I mean, in the DDMS I can see that my file has the following permission : -rw-------

I'd like to have somthing like this : -rw-rw----

he file is at the following at the location :
data\data\com.blablabla.foo\databases\myfile

How should I do ?

I create my file as follows :

```
InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url1.openStream(),1);
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(PATH + url[1]);

NewDatabaseName = url[1];

byte data[] = new byte[1024];

long total = 0;

while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
     total += count;
    // publishing the progress....
     publishProgress((int)(total*100/lenghtOfFile));
     output.write(data, 0, count);
}

output.flush();
output.close();
input.close();
```

When I wrote this code : 
FileOutputStream fileOutput = openFileOutput("myApp.apk", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

I have an error on openFileOutput method that tell me that I have to create it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I wrote this code : FileOutputStream fileOutput = openFileOutput("myApp.apk", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
>
> I have an error on openFileOutput method that tell me that I have to create it.

`openFileOutput()` is a method on `Context`, so you would call that on your `Activity`, `Service`, etc.

Comment: I use it in an asynctask, the openFileOut is recognized for one String argument, but not for String and int arguments.

Comment: @Miroufle: AFAIK, there is no single-parameter `openFileOutput()` anywhere in the Android SDK.

Comment: Yes, you're right (I also saw it in the Android developper documentation)  but why do I have a this error ?
Anyway, is there another method to change file permission ?

Comment: @Miroufle: "why do I have a this error ? " -- I have no idea. "is there another method to change file permission ?" -- nothing that is supported. Find some sample code that uses `openFileOutput()` and try it in a separate clean project. Once you get that working, determine what the difference is between what the sample is doing and what your current code is doing.

Comment: THank you, Strangely the openFileOutput() method contains 1 argument in the async taks and two anywhere else. Thanks for your help to solve my issue.